# Why aren't the braces showing

Tags: math-mode, errors, delimiters

I have this `tex`: `\(\mu_{A}\left(x\right)\in \[0,1  \right\]\)`

The issue here is that `[` and `]` are not showing around `0,1`, why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are using latex (you didn't say) and that you got an error message (you didn't say that either). `\[` in latex is a command to start display math, to get a `[` just use `[` also you need `\left` on the `[` or (better) don't use `\right` with the `]`

Comment: `\[0,1 \right\]` is wrong, simply `[0,1]`

Comment: @David Carlisle. Thanks for your reply. Yes, you are right, I'm using `LaTex`. I didn't get an error message, just didn't get the expected result

Comment: You _must have got an error message, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\(\mu_{A}(x)\in [0,1]\)

\end{document}
```

If you change the expression to the one in your question then you get the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 \(\mu_{A}\left(x\right)\in \[
                                 0,1 \right\]\)
? h
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
?
```

where the linebreak after `\[` indicates that is how far TeX had got before issuing the error.

Comment: I bet that if I had answered, I wouldn't have got an upvote... :-)

Comment: @karlkoeller I'd have voted for you:-)