# Sequential \frac that aren't nested

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I'm new to Latex and am having trouble troubleshooting an equation that I can't get to display correctly. The equation I am trying to create in Latex is:
[image]

...but I keep getting nested fractions starting with the 3rd to last term so it appears like:
[image]

The code I am using is:

```
\begin{equation}
\centering
\frac{\partial UB}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial UUB }{\partial x}+\frac{\partial WUB}{\partial z}=gB\sin\alpha+g\cos\alpha B\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}-\frac{g\cos\alpha B}{\rho} \[\int_\eta^z \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}dz\]+\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial B\tau_x_x}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial B\tau_x_z}{\partial z}+qBU_x
\label{eqn:horizontalmomentum}
\end{equation}
```

I'm also getting a whole bunch of errors:

[image]

Comment: Different cause, same symptom, same solution: [Why aren't the braces showing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148187/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `\[ ... \]` inside a math expression. USe

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}\label{eqn:horizontalmomentum}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial UB}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial UUB }{\partial x}
  +\frac{\partial WUB}{\partial z} & = gB\sin\alpha
  +g\cos\alpha B\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}
  -\frac{g\cos\alpha B}{\rho} \int_\eta^z \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}dz \\
 & 
  +\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial B{\tau_x}_x}{\partial x}
  +\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial B{\tau_x}_z}{\partial z}+qBU_x
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you need a little bit of space after the `&` in the second line?  Maybe swap the `&` and the `=` in the first line and add a `\quad` in the second?

Comment: One could have a better design (to my taste) with multlined, but the question has been marked as duplicate…